# Calculate the following definite integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Calculate the following integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^\beta\frac{e^{ax-bx^2}}{ce^{ax}+d}dx,$$
where all of $a,b,c,d >0$.

I have tried to use change-of-variable, such as $e^{ax}=u$ and $e^{-bx^2}=u$ and neither of them works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *possible* approach
$$I=\int\frac{e^{ax-bx^2}}{ce^{ax}+d}\,dx=\frac 1 c\int\frac{e^{ax-bx^2}}{e^{ax}+k}\,dx \qquad \text{where} \qquad k=\frac d c$$ Expanding around $k=0$
$$\frac{e^{ax-bx^2}}{e^{ax}+k}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n e^{-(nax+bx^2)}\, k^n$$ Complete the square to get
$$J_n=\int  e^{-(nax+bx^2)}\,dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\, e^{\frac{a^2 n^2}{4 b}}}{2 \sqrt{b}}\,\text{erf}\left(\frac{a n+2 b x}{2 \sqrt{b}}\right)$$ and finally
$$I=\frac 1 c\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n J_n\, \left(\frac{d}{c}\right)^n$$